# Python Matplotlib Finance: Get the quarterly EPS of a stock

Tags: python, matplotlib, yahoo-finance

I am using Matplotlib Finance with Python to obtain stock quotes from Yahoo! Finance.

I am wondering if there is a way to obtain the EPS (earnings per share) for the current quarter as well as for the quarters of the past 5 years (i.e past 20 quarters) using Matplotlib Finance.

If not, can anyone direct me to a library for python which has this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me.

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/goog/financials'
text_soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read()) #read in

titles = text_soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'rowTitle'})
for title in titles:
    if 'EPS (Basic)' in title.text:
        print [td.text for td in title.findNextSiblings(attrs={'class': 'valueCell'}) if td.text]
```

Result:
[u'15.10', u'16.42', u'18.29', u'20.27', u'23.88']
[u'-', u'8.75%', u'11.38%', u'10.85%', u'17.78%']